# How to insert Perl variables into Sqlite3

Tags: perl, sqlite

I want to insert values into Sqlite3 table using Perl DBI. I was able to insert hard coded values without any problem. When I tried to use perl variables, then I get an error "DBD::SQLite::db do failed: no such column:"

This works:

```
$dbh->do("insert into Gene values (12, 'AAAAAA', 66, 86, 76)");
```

But this code

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO Gene values (NULL, $sequence, $siteNumber, $begin, $length)");
```

throws the error

```
DBD::SQLite::db do failed: no such column
```

Comment: **Don't say "I got an error". Always say "Here is the error I got" and then show us the exact error.** Don't paraphrase it. Don't retype it. Cut & paste the error message exactly from your screen.

Comment: "DBD::SQLite::db do failed: no such column" is the error I got.

Comment: The first thing you want to do to debug this is to `print "INSERT INTO Gene values (NULL, $sequence, $siteNumber, $begin, $length)";` so you know what SQL command is being executed.  We can't magically tell what the values of those 4 variables are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should always `prepare` and `execute` your SQL statements and use placeholders for variable values as a matter of course.

Try this code

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Gene VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$sth->execute(undef, $sequence, $siteNumber, $begin, $length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem will have been at $sequence, which required quoting to be a valid SQL string literal in the insert statement. As a result it thought you were trying to refer to a column called AAAAAA, and not the string 'AAAAAA' that you intended. Perl's string interpolation doesn't add the quotes for you.

Placeholders and $dbh->prepapre are by far the most robust solution here though (for example, what to do if your string contains the quote character ' ? $dbh->prepare already has that coded correctly).